# Asynchronous merging of web responses in clojure

Tags: asynchronous, clojure

I am trying to write a piece of code that would:

- access 2 webservice with some request
- the response will be sequences of objects, each object identified by id, the responses sorted by ID in ascending order
- the responses will be large and streamed (or gzip chunked)
- the result will be a merge of data from the two inputs based on IDs

What I try to achieve is that once the corresponding parts of responses are available, the output should be written out. I also don't want to wait for the whole response to be in place, since this will run out of memory. I want to start streaming output as soon as I can and keep as little in memory as possible.

What would be a good way to start?

I have taken a look at aleph and lamina, also async.http.client. It seems that these tools could help me, but I struggle with figuring out how to have one piece of code that would react to having the same part of responses from both webservices.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this (using aleph - which under the hood used lamina channels abstraction).

- Use `sync-http-request` to create the 2 http request
- Get the `:body` from the above created 2 request object. Ex: at https://github.com/ztellman/aleph/wiki/Consuming-and-Broadcasting-a-Twitter-Stream
- The `:body` is a lamina channel, use lamina `join` method to join the 2 channels into one channel
- Subscribe to the above channel (which was result of `join` call).

Now the subscription callback will receive each JSON object as soon as it arrives on the either of the channels and you can than have a local `atom` which is a map with key being the value on which you want to combine the result from the 2 channels and value being a vector which will store values for the same key. So this will go something like this:

- On receiving an item in callback, check if the local `atom` map has the key already
- If key is already, store or do some other processing with the 2 items (one already in the map and other that you just received) for the key and remove the key from the map.
- If key not there, create the key and value as `[item]` i.e the vector of one item that is being received now.

Comment: thanks for enlightening me on the join of the lamina channels. I will implement this and see how well that goes.